# Optimize method for searching(ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-core

I have a method to get value from the database via criteria

Here is this method

```
public async Task<ListResultDto<PropertyTenancyDto>> GetPropertySuggestions(string address,
        int? landlordId)
    {
        var tenantId = AbpSession.TenantId;
        if (tenantId == null)
        {
            throw new UserFriendlyException(L("FunctionalityIsNotAvailable"));
        }


        var query = _propertyRepository.GetAll()
            .Include(i => i.Addresses)
            .Include(x => x.Sites)
            .WhereIf(!address.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(),
                p => (p.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().Line1
                          .StartsWith(address.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                      p.TenantId == tenantId && p.Status == PropertyStatus.ReadyToLet) ||
                     (p.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().Line1
                          .StartsWith(address.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                      p.LandlordId == landlordId && p.Status == PropertyStatus.ReadyToLet));

        var properties = await query.ProjectTo<PropertyTenancyDto>(ObjectMapper).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToListAsync();
        return new ListResultDto<PropertyTenancyDto>(properties);
    }
```

It works well, but on huge amount of data (67K values) in database it works very slow (15-30 seconds)

This method is searching for a property via address string

I tried to optimize database query and create index to the `Line1` field. But it not helps.

This I get in expression of query

> value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[PM101.PMProperties.Property]).Include(i => i.Addresses).Include(x => x.Sites).Where(p => (((p.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().Line1.StartsWith(value(PM101.Tenancies.TenancyAppService+<>c__DisplayClass27_0).address.Trim(), OrdinalIgnoreCase) AndAlso (Convert(p.TenantId, Nullable`1) == value(PM101.Tenancies.TenancyAppService+<>c__DisplayClass27_0).tenantId)) AndAlso (Convert(p.Status, Int32) == 3)) OrElse ((p.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().Line1.StartsWith(value(PM101.Tenancies.TenancyAppService+<>c__DisplayClass27_0).address.Trim(), OrdinalIgnoreCase) AndAlso (p.LandlordId == value(PM101.Tenancies.TenancyAppService+<>c__DisplayClass27_0).landlordId)) AndAlso (Convert(p.Status, Int32) == 3))))

Any more advice ho I can speed up this query?

Comment: What exactly does `GetAll` and `WhereIf` do?

Comment: WhereIf `asp.net boilerplate` methods to filter value by condition

 Filters a <see cref="IQueryable{T}"/> by given predicate if given condition is true. @juharr

Comment: Same stuff for get all https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Repositories @juharr

Comment: In that case the issue is that you are doing a `LIKE` comparison (what the `StartsWith` will translate to) and that requires a table scan and cannot take advantage of an index.  If there is anyway you can change either the data in the DB or the value you are searching with to be an exact match that would be the best way to speed this up.

Comment: So how I can rewrite code to speed it up? @juharr

Comment: It completely depends on the data in the DB and the value of `address`.   Presumeably `address` is less data that what you have in `Line1`.  So you'd either need to get `address` to be an exact match of `Line1` or if that isn't possible then you could try adding a column in the DB that has a truncated value of `Line1` that would match whatever you have in `address`, or at least match some minimum length so you could index that and then have less to scan for the `StartsWith`.